# Calling a web service method in javascript when wsdl is on client itself

Tags: javascript, web-services

I am new to javascript. I have a wsdl file available on my system corresponding to a  web service. I need to call a web method using that wsdl file. As wsdl is on my system, Javascript doesnot allow access to local system.

Could anyone please let me know how to call a method of the webservice ?

Please reply asap.

Comment: You need to run a local web-server (`wamp` on windows) and create a web-service using a server-side scripting language (e.g. `php`) then send your request from `javascript` to your local web-server (via `ajax`). WSDL files are just a structured documentation of a webservice. In Fact they do not anything, they just show how a webservice's methods work.